# What exceptions are propagated to Client application code in Kafka API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using Kafka Java API v2.1. I want to know what kind of exceptions will be propagated to the client application code from the underlying API

This is my produced callback code for send call:

```
        @Override
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
        if (e == null) {
            if (LOG.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
                LOG.finest("Sent message " + mySentRecord
                           + " with offset " + metadata.offset()
                           + " on topic:partition "
                           + metadata.topic() + ":" + metadata.partition());
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException |
                   NotEnoughReplicasException |
                   TimeoutException exception )
            {
                StringWriter outError = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(outError));
                LOG.warning(outError.toString());
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                throw new ApplicationDeath(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am catching NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException, NotEnoughReplicasException and TimeoutException but I never see anything except timeout out exceptions when I kill the brokers in ISR. I don't see any disconnect exceptions or not enough replicas exceptions.

I know that Kafka API will be retrying connections internally but I want to get notified of such attempts in application code. Similary, I don't see any such exceptions in consumer code except metadata timeouts.

How can I achieve this and get notified about any connection breaks, not enough replicas etc.? What other exceptions I should be catching and handling here?

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

First, never `throw e` and catch it.

Instead check `if (e instanceof ExceptionClass)`

---

These are all listed [in the JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html)

Reformatted here for readablilty.

#### Non-Retriable exceptions (fatal, the message will never be sent):

- InvalidTopicException
- OffsetMetadataTooLargeException
- RecordBatchTooLargeException
- RecordTooLargeException
- UnknownServerException

#### Retriable exceptions (transient, may be covered by increasing #.retries):

- CorruptRecordException
- InvalidMetadataException
- NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException
- NotEnoughReplicasException
- OffsetOutOfRangeException
- TimeoutException
- UnknownTopicOrPartitionException

Comment: Is throwing and catching a bad practice? I did saw the exceptions in Javadoc however I am not getting any of the exceptions in the callback.

Comment: Yes it's a bad practice. If checking is always much faster than catching Exceptions. And I'm not sure what you tell you, but in the most cases I've seen, nobody ever checks each of these because they only care if data actually did arrive. Besides, if you're not sending 5MB sized byte arrays, then no you'd never get TooLarge exception. Similarly, a producer getting OutOfRange or InvalidMetadata would be strange, and CorruptRecord is very rare, and you'd really have to invoke packet manipulation in-flight of the response

Comment: Regarding killing brokers in ISR, you need to shutdown each of the leader brokers, then you'd be getting UnknownTopicOrPartitionException, I think, not NotEnoughReplicas